# Generating WAR files from a multiproject Maven configuration

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-war-plugin

I have a [Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) project, with 4 components Web, Persistence, Common and Other.

The relevant stuff off my [POM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) files:

Parent POM:

```
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>components/TestWeb</module>
    <module>components/TestOther</module>
    <module>components/TestPersistence</module>
    <module>components/TestCommon</module>
</modules>


<build>
    <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <dependentWarExcludes>
                    **/hibernate.cfg.xml,**/sql-map-config.xml,**/web.xml,WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/**
                </dependentWarExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
 </build>
```

common pom:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>test-common</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

persistence pom:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>test-persistence</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>


<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-common</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

web pom:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>test-web</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>TestWeb</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-common</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>


  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-persistence</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>


  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-other</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
```

Maybe I broke something in the copy&paste, but the XML is valid.

- when I run mvn package, the project [WAR file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_%28Sun_file_format%29) isn't created, but all components packages are created and well formed.
- if, then, I run `mvn war:war`, the WAR file is generated empty.

How can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having plugins in the root project does not work. You can configure the plugins here, like this

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

but they still have to be referenced in the subprojects to be active (except for plugins that are part of the default process, like maven-compiler-plugin and maven-resource-plugin).

So either you move your war-plugin configuration to `pluginManagement` in the root project and include

```
<build>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <execution>
            <goals>...</goals>
        </execution>
    </plugin>
</build>
```

in your war project or you move the entire configuration into the war.

Additional note:
Make sure the order of the modules in the root pom is aligned to the dependency relations between the projects (In your case just reverse the order).

Comment: Thanks Arian. So, the idea is have all packed in the web war, rigth? (I thougth that will be a war in the parent project)

Comment: `Having plugins in the root project does not work` Hmm... plugins and their configuration **are** inherited so it works. Whether the war plugin should be configured there is another story, but it "works".

Comment: @Pascal: Ok, let me rephrase that: I does not do what Hugo wants. Even though the settings are inherited, the plugin still has to be referenced in the subproject to have it executed.

Comment: No, this is not true either, the plugin and its configuration are inherited (by all projects actually) as you can check using `mvn help:effective-pom`. So the configuration is active when `war:war` is executed during `package` for the `war` module. In other words, that's not the problem (even if I wouldn't configure the war plugin in the parent project like the OP did, but this is another story).

Comment: And by the way, the order of modules doesn't matter. Maven derives the build order from dependencies, not from the order of modules.

Answer (score 1):

I created a similar project structure and pasted the POMs you provided but couldn't reproduce the problem. Running `mvn package` from the aggregating pom just works as expected:

```
$ mvn package 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Unnamed - com.test:test:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT ............ SUCCESS [5.819s]
[INFO] Unnamed - com.test:test-common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT ..... SUCCESS [3.343s]
[INFO] Unnamed - com.test:test-persistence:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT  SUCCESS [0.136s]
[INFO] Unnamed - com.test:test-other:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT ...... SUCCESS [0.079s]
[INFO] Unnamed - com.test:test-web:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT ........ SUCCESS [1.899s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

And produces the following result:

```
$ tree .
.
├── components
│   ├── TestCommon
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── target
│   │       ├── maven-archiver
│   │       │   └── pom.properties
│   │       └── test-common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
│   ├── TestOther
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── target
│   │       ├── maven-archiver
│   │       │   └── pom.properties
│   │       └── test-other-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
│   ├── TestPersistence
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── target
│   │       ├── maven-archiver
│   │       │   └── pom.properties
│   │       └── test-persistence-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
│   └── TestWeb
│       ├── pom.xml
│       ├── src
│       │   └── main
│       │       └── webapp
│       │           ├── index.jsp
│       │           └── WEB-INF
│       │               └── web.xml
│       └── target
│           ├── maven-archiver
│           │   └── pom.properties
│           ├── test-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
│           │   ├── index.jsp
│           │   ├── META-INF
│           │   └── WEB-INF
│           │       ├── classes
│           │       ├── lib
│           │       │   ├── test-common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
│           │       │   ├── test-other-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
│           │       │   └── test-persistence-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
│           │       └── web.xml
│           └── test-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
└── pom.xml
```

So your problem must have something to do with your WAR project itself, its structure or something like this. Please show its structure and the output of Maven when running `war:war` on it.

---

By the way, here is how a POM should typically look like in a multi-modules build:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <!--groupId>com.test</groupId--> <!-- unnecessary, you inherit it -->
  <artifactId>test-web</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <!--version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version--> <!-- unnecessary, you inherit it -->
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId> <!-- DRY, use built-in properties -->
      <artifactId>test-common</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version> <!-- DRY, use built-in properties -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>test-persistence</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>test-other</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Another thing, the war plugin configuration from the parent project **is** inherited (you can check that by running `help:effective-pom` in the web module) but it would make sense to configure it in the web module itself.